# Italian Navy Records from 1820 to 1840

Tags: 19th-century, navy, italy, merchant-navy

I am researching about my family tree and I finally found something on my great great great grandfather.

I have discovered that he was from Italian Navy posted in Sistre Levante from 1838 to 1842. I have already sent emails to this comune and couldn't find his records ( I'm looking for his date of birth and place of birth ).  I realized the army ( or navy ) might have these records.

Is there any website, database, document or anything that could point me towards navy registers for the period of 1820 to 1840?

Comment: I think you will have be more specific about what region of Italy he was from. Italy, as a unified country, did not exist until 1861. Before that, you are looking at about 8 different kingdoms. It appears Sistre Levant probably was part of the Kingdom of Sardinia. Fortunately for you, the Kingdom of Sardinia was the driving power behind Italian unification, so of all the kingdoms, its records are most likely to survive.